# Android Bitmap in View TouchListener

Tags: android, view, ontouchlistener

I have a bitmap in View. When I use `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`, It controls View touch.

But I want to move or touch Bitmap. When I touch On Bitmap, View is moving. But Bitmap is not moving. I want to move Bitmap When I touch Bitmap. Not view

```
    public class TestView extends View {
    public TestView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        Bitmap target = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.image), 150, 150, false);

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event){

            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
            int action = event.getAction();

            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (x_t <= x && x < x_t + target.getWidth() &&
                        y_t <= y && y < y_t + target.getHeight()) {

                    View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(this);

                    viewGroup.getChildAt(1).startDrag(null, //data to be dragged
                            shadowBuilder, //drag shadow
                            this, //local data about the drag and drop operation
                            0   //no needed flags
                    );
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your `onDraw` method like?

Comment: canvas.drawBitmap(target, x, y null);

Comment: so replace `float x = event.getX();` with `x = event.getX();`, the same for `y`

Comment: Why? float x = touchposition. I need to know that touch target or not ?

Comment: so who changes `x` and `y` used inside `onDraw`?